# Pandas' Concatenation Performance

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading data from the same table, but it is very large.  1 Million plus records.  I thought it would be better to create chunks of 250,000, so I get 4 DataFrames.

```
frames = []
for chunk in chunks(some_very_large_list, 250000):
   frames.append(pd.DataFrame(data=chunk, columns=['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

When I call `pd.concat(frames)` it is taking an extremely long time to merge everything together.  What is the best way to speed up this process?

Comment: Did you compare it against loading a monolithic block with all data?

Comment: Yes, that performance isn't great because I have to load everything from a non-native support DB.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try, that may or may not help:

1. Pre-allocate the memory for the large data, and place each chunk in its place.
2. Work with 2d numpy array (if possible) and transfer everything to a dataframe afterwords.

Comment: Can you expands on how to do Item #2?

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice if you could provide the code in order to do so based on the example that is given?

Answer (score 0):

For my case which seems to be similar to yours, the best way i found was to use append function:

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

dataframe.append(frames, ignore_index=True)

Comment: Does this method create a new dataframe? Does the frames object have to be a dataframe or can I pass in a list of frames?

Comment: No, it does not return a new dataframe but it updates the DataFrame object named dataframe in my example. You must pass a list of DataFrame objects (like your frames variable which is a list of DataFrame).